# Owl Carousel is not working with direction RTL

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, owl-carousel

The Owl Carousel slider is not working with RTL. I add `rtl: true` in the configuration. But it's not loading the slider. The slider space is there and navigation is showing. But only the slider content is not showing. How can I fix this problem?

My code is given below:

```
<div class="row" id="brand-slider">
    <div class="item">
        <a href="#">
        <img src="{base_url()}assets/upload/brands/{$v.image}" class="img-responsive img-centered" alt="{$v.name}">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="#">
        <img src="{base_url()}assets/upload/brands/{$v.image}" class="img-responsive img-centered" alt="{$v.name}">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="#">
        <img src="{base_url()}assets/upload/brands/{$v.image}" class="img-responsive img-centered" alt="{$v.name}">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="#">
        <img src="{base_url()}assets/upload/brands/{$v.image}" class="img-responsive img-centered" alt="{$v.name}">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $("#brand-slider").owlCarousel({
        rtl: true,
        loop: true,
        items: 6,
        pagination: false,
        autoPlay: true,
        responsive: true
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank god, that issue waste my long time. Now i found the issue and fixed. Just add style "direction: ltr" to parent Id or class. In my case <div class="row" id="brand-slider" style="direction: ltr;">

Comment: I think they need to specify it in their documentation :/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This solution worked for me

Add **direction: ltr;** to the the **.owl-stage-outer** class in the **owl.carousel.min.css** file , as following

```
.owl-stage-outer{
 position:relative;
 overflow:hidden;
 -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
 direction: ltr;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

just add to your CSS

```
.owl-carousel{
 direction: ltr !important;
}
```

- other solutions will work but will make the  carousel jumps as you drag  it right or left

Answer (score 2):

**For make Owl-Carousel-Version-1 RTL follow these steps :**

**step-1** : add this codes to your css file

```
.owl-carousel .owl-item {
   float: right !important;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper-outer {
   direction: rtl !important;
}
```

**step-2** : open owl.carousel.js then search transform and replace this lines

```
"-webkit-transform": "translate3D(" + pixels + "px, 0px, 0px)",
"-moz-transform": "translate3d(" + pixels + "px, 0px, 0px)",
"-o-transform": "translate3d(" + pixels + "px, 0px, 0px)",
"-ms-transform": "translate3d(" + pixels + "px, 0px, 0px)",
"transform": "translate3d(" + pixels + "px, 0px,0px)"
```

to this (we have to change pixel to -pixel) :

```
"-webkit-transform": "translate3D(" + -pixels + "px, 0px, 0px)",
"-moz-transform": "translate3d(" + -pixels + "px, 0px, 0px)",
"-o-transform": "translate3d(" + -pixels + "px, 0px, 0px)",
"-ms-transform": "translate3d(" + -pixels + "px, 0px, 0px)",
"transform": "translate3d(" + -pixels + "px, 0px,0px)"
```

**Owl-Carousel-Version-2 already has this feature.**

Answer (score 0):

Add This Code To Your Css File

```
.owl-carousel .owl-item,
.owl-wrapper {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find this code `translate3d("+b+"px,0px,0px)` in owl.carousel.min.js and change it to this code `translate3d("+(-b)+"px,0px,0px)`.

Answer (score 0):

In the owl.carousel.js file

search for `transform` you should find something like this

`transform: 'translate3d("+b+"px,0px,0px)'`

see this `"+b+"` replace it with `"+-b+"` it ends up like this

`transform: "translate3d(" + -b + "px,0px, 0px)"`

Notes this will not work in `ltr` versions so in my case I am using dynamic application so made 2 files and I called the english version without minus  `" + b + "` and the `rtl` I added this minus.

it may help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed there is an option for owl slider

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    rtl:true,
```

So you can use that and it will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Upadet your owl carousal version, use owl carousel 2 or update your js and css file.Then use  **rtl:true,**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).