# Owl carousel multiple rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

I just want to show multiple rows and with owl dots. Like this way.

[image]

But it seems there are no nay inbuilt option for this. So I tried to give

```
.owl-item {
width: 20%;
}
```

so it will be in 5 items in row. But it didn't work at all. I think plugin styles will be applied.

Here is the fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/7mt5aL2x/

Any solutions?

Comment: I dont think owl has this feature, but slick slider has this feature  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22545466/how-can-i-create-a-carousel-with-multiple-rows

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it.

Comment: NO! its possible, just make grid and place them in `item` class of owl carousel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple idea using `flex`

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    items:1,
    nav: true
})
```

```css
.owl-carousel .item {
    background: #4DC7A0;
    padding: 1rem;
}

body{
  padding: 10px;
}.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>  
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>  
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>  
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>  
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>
      
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>  
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>  
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>  
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>  
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>
      
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved my day.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you

Comment: i have a problem with this.i used <html dir="rtl"> but carousel not working.my mean carousel not showing.

Comment: @Mohadeseh plz try this solution 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38939739/owl-carousel-is-not-working-with-direction-rtl

Comment: thanks @Awais. but i have another problem. i asked thiss link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70752128/how-to-owl-carousel-multiple-rows

Answer (score 17):

As I needed a **true responsive multiple rows owl carousel** (meaning it keeps slides ordered for all window sizes) for a project, I stumbled upon this question during my initial search, but found no real helpful or complete answers to it.

So I implemented it myself, and figured it could still help you, or someone(s) else in the future, so I have set up a **codepen**: https://codepen.io/Tolc/pen/OJXyKpo

What it achieves is basically this kind of responsive carousel:

```
desktop                   tablet                    mobile
cols: 3, rows: 2          cols: 2, rows: 3          cols: 1, rows: 2
1 2 3 -> 7 8 9            1 2 -> 7 8                1 -> 3 -> ...
4 5 6    10...            3 4    9 10               2    4
                          5 6    ...
```

This is just an example, the code works with **any number of columns and rows and any breakpoint**.

The basic principle is the same as the other answers: injecting wrapper divs that act as columns. But my implementation handles responsiveness so you don't lose any of Owl Carousel's features.

Html looks like this (only important part are the **data-slide-index** attributes):

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="slide" data-slide-index="0">1</div>
    <div class="slide" data-slide-index="1">2</div>
    <div class="slide" data-slide-index="2">3</div>
    ...
</div>
```

The whole js is a bit long but here it is (I tried to comment the interesting parts):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var el = $('.owl-carousel');
  
  var carousel;
  var carouselOptions = {
    margin: 20,
    nav: true,
    dots: true,
    slideBy: 'page',
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1,
        rows: 2 //custom option not used by Owl Carousel, but used by the algorithm below
      },
      768: {
        items: 2,
        rows: 3 //custom option not used by Owl Carousel, but used by the algorithm below
      },
      991: {
        items: 3,
        rows: 2 //custom option not used by Owl Carousel, but used by the algorithm below
      }
    }
  };

  //Taken from Owl Carousel so we calculate width the same way
  var viewport = function() {
    var width;
    if (carouselOptions.responsiveBaseElement && carouselOptions.responsiveBaseElement !== window) {
      width = $(carouselOptions.responsiveBaseElement).width();
    } else if (window.innerWidth) {
      width = window.innerWidth;
    } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientWidth) {
      width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    } else {
      console.warn('Can not detect viewport width.');
    }
    return width;
  };

  var severalRows = false;
  var orderedBreakpoints = [];
  for (var breakpoint in carouselOptions.responsive) {
    if (carouselOptions.responsive[breakpoint].rows > 1) {
      severalRows = true;
    }
    orderedBreakpoints.push(parseInt(breakpoint));
  }
  
  //Custom logic is active if carousel is set up to have more than one row for some given window width
  if (severalRows) {
    orderedBreakpoints.sort(function (a, b) {
      return b - a;
    });
    var slides = el.find('[data-slide-index]');
    var slidesNb = slides.length;
    if (slidesNb > 0) {
      var rowsNb;
      var previousRowsNb = undefined;
      var colsNb;
      var previousColsNb = undefined;

      //Calculates number of rows and cols based on current window width
      var updateRowsColsNb = function () {
        var width =  viewport();
        for (var i = 0; i < orderedBreakpoints.length; i++) {
          var breakpoint = orderedBreakpoints[i];
          if (width >= breakpoint || i == (orderedBreakpoints.length - 1)) {
            var breakpointSettings = carouselOptions.responsive['' + breakpoint];
            rowsNb = breakpointSettings.rows;
            colsNb = breakpointSettings.items;
            break;
          }
        }
      };

      var updateCarousel = function () {
        updateRowsColsNb();

        //Carousel is recalculated if and only if a change in number of columns/rows is requested
        if (rowsNb != previousRowsNb || colsNb != previousColsNb) {
          var reInit = false;
          if (carousel) {
            //Destroy existing carousel if any, and set html markup back to its initial state
            carousel.trigger('destroy.owl.carousel');
            carousel = undefined;
            slides = el.find('[data-slide-index]').detach().appendTo(el);
            el.find('.fake-col-wrapper').remove();
            reInit = true;
          }


          //This is the only real 'smart' part of the algorithm

          //First calculate the number of needed columns for the whole carousel
          var perPage = rowsNb * colsNb;
          var pageIndex = Math.floor(slidesNb / perPage);
          var fakeColsNb = pageIndex * colsNb + (slidesNb >= (pageIndex * perPage + colsNb) ? colsNb : (slidesNb % colsNb));

          //Then populate with needed html markup
          var count = 0;
          for (var i = 0; i < fakeColsNb; i++) {
            //For each column, create a new wrapper div
            var fakeCol = $('<div class="fake-col-wrapper"></div>').appendTo(el);
            for (var j = 0; j < rowsNb; j++) {
              //For each row in said column, calculate which slide should be present
              var index = Math.floor(count / perPage) * perPage + (i % colsNb) + j * colsNb;
              if (index < slidesNb) {
                //If said slide exists, move it under wrapper div
                slides.filter('[data-slide-index=' + index + ']').detach().appendTo(fakeCol);
              }
              count++;
            }
          }
          //end of 'smart' part

          previousRowsNb = rowsNb;
          previousColsNb = colsNb;

          if (reInit) {
            //re-init carousel with new markup
            carousel = el.owlCarousel(carouselOptions);
          }
        }
      };

      //Trigger possible update when window size changes
      $(window).on('resize', updateCarousel);

      //We need to execute the algorithm once before first init in any case
      updateCarousel();
    }
  }

  //init
  carousel = el.owlCarousel(carouselOptions);
});
```

Full codepen to see it in action: https://codepen.io/Tolc/pen/OJXyKpo

Comment: This should definitely be considered as the correct answer.  It provides the requested functionality while also maintaining the responsive options that go along with it.

Comment: Even better response for responsiveness purposes

Comment: Thanks! Worked great for my application. I appreciate the contribution.

Answer (score 5):

You can add several objects in one item and adapt the css to make them longer:

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item"><h4>1</h4><h4>2</h4></div>
  <div class="item"><h4>3</h4><h4>4</h4></div>
  <div class="item"><h4>5</h4><h4>6</h4></div>
  <div class="item"><h4>7</h4><h4>8</h4></div>
  <div class="item"><h4>9</h4><h4>10</h4></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yL8q6p3c/

Comment: +1 ! I dont know why anyone would not simply do this example. The slider is for the amount of slides required. Just place multiple items in one slide!

Answer (score 1):

As long as you create your grid and place it inside **video-item**, it should be fine.

This is how I made a video carousel of 2 rows.

```
<div class="video-carousel-container container">
<div class="row slider-carousel-video owl-carousel">
  @foreach ($videos as $item)
    <div class="video-item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-1"> 
      <iframe width="320" height="185" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{$item->video}}" frameborder="0" 
      allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
      </iframe>
      <iframe width="320" height="185" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{$item->video}}" frameborder="0" 
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
        </iframe>
    </div>
  @endforeach
</div>
```