# How to make my child div go under on owl carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, carousel, owl-carousel

I want it to display 6 articles like this, and then be able to slide to the next frame with another 6 articles:
[view img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Di4i5.png)

When I use this code, it only shows 3 articles per frame:

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
loop:false,
margin:10,

}
```

[view img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yicI3.png)

When I use "responsive", it shows 6 articles but all in horizontal:

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
loop:false,
margin:10,
responsive:{
    1000:{
        items:6
    },
}
```

[view img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZxAy.png)

How can I display 3 articles on top, and 3 articles on the bottom?

Comment: there are many solutions - it's just simple CSS for owl-item

Comment: Duplicate one here with answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60429910/owl-carousel-multiple-rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60429910/owl-carousel-multiple-rows)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Owl carousel multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60429910/owl-carousel-multiple-rows)

Answer (score 0):

you should be use the full responsive codes for all of screen resolution

example

```
responsive:{
1000:{items:5,loop:true},
900:{items:4,loop:true},
800:{items:4,loop:true},
600:{items:3,loop:true},
500:{items:3,loop:true},
1:{items:2,loop:true}
},
```

You should also check the CSS style codes to be accurate
Insert the link for better review so others can help better

According to your image, the problem is that the CSS is not set correctly